# Специалисты по БД, выручайте) Необходимо найти 15 структур оператора select

Tags: sql, база-данных

Преподаватель дал задание на курсовую разобрать оператор select и сделать 15 уникальных запросов по нему. И позже добавил, что 15 найти невозможно. Что он имел ввиду -  не ясно. Но пока что нашел такие:

1 Подзапрос в Select

2 Подзапрос Select и Union

3 Подзапрос Select в Where

4 Подзапрос Select во From

5 Подзапрос Select в Having

6 Select + Order By

7 Select + Group By

Пожалуйста, не нужно пересылать структуру оператора select, я видел, но видимо плохо смотрю и в упор не понимаю какие еще существуют. Если есть возможность объяснить простым языком, то донесите до нерадивого студента, пожалуйста :)

Comment: Мне очень жаль, но, я думаю, что многое зависит от того, что понимается под "уникальными запросами"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Константный SELECT
2. Простой SELECT
3. Многотабличный SELECT
4. SELECT с отбором (WHERE)
5. Группирующий SELECT (GROUP BY)
6. SELECT с пост-отбором (HAVING)
7. SELECT с сортировкой/ограничением (ORDER BY, LIMIT)
8. SELECT в простом подзапросе
9. SELECT в коррелированном подзапросе
10. SELECT в CTE
11. SELECT с обратным доступом (LATERAL)
12. SELECT в UNION
13. Итерационный SELECT (с использованием переменных)
14. Рекурсивный SELECT (в рекурсивном CTE)
15. SELECT с выводом в переменную/файл (SELECT INTO)

---

Список сильно зависит от СУБД и версии. Все указанные типы запросов перечислены для актуальной версии MySQL.

Comment: Надо преподавателям читать so что бы видеть кто списал)))

Comment: @nick_n_a Обычно преподаватели, научившись учить, разучиваются читать...

Comment: Кто-то уже подписался на тему, будет ни есть хорошо, если завтра он тыкнет сюда пальцем)) @Akina Спасибо огромное, буду пробовать)

Comment: @NEONMOON, я подписался, т.к. было интересно :)

Answer (score 1):

8. SELECT DISTINCT
9. SELECT + LIMIT
10. SELECT + OFFSET
11. SELECT + FOR UPDATE OF
12. SELECT +  WINDOW